# Undefined symbol boost::system:detail::system_category_instance

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-filesystem, boost-beast, boost-system

I've build boost with c++17 standard with clang on macOS Mojave when compiling my playground program that uses *beast* and *asio* I get the following error:
[image]

This is my make file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13.1)
project (Playground)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USER_MULITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/boost-1.68.0")
set(Boost_INLCUDE_DIR "/usr/local/boost-1.68.0/include")
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE "/usr/local/boost-1.68.0/lib")

find_package(Boost 1.68.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)

set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
    src/http_client/http_client.hpp
    src/http_client/http_client.cpp)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories("/usr/local/boost-1.68.0/include")
    add_executable (Playground ${SOURCES})
    set_property(TARGET Playground PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
    target_include_directories(Playground PRIVATE ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(Playground ${BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
                                     ${BOOST_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

I've compiled boost with steps described in this tutorial:
[Compiling Boost with Clang](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/08/07/compiling-boost-gcc-clang-macos/).

Clang version:
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0

Is there anything else I've to take into account? I've read a lot of posts, etc. where it's suggested to compile boost in the same c++ standard that should be used in the project itself.

EDIT:
Matthieu Brucher's hint with the variable names (Boost_ vs. BOOST_) did the trick. Now it's working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Especially the last answer: you don't have the right architecture installed/built for boost, only the 32bits when you also need 64bits.

Comment: Also the real variable name is `Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY` not `BOOST_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matthieu Brucher's hint with the variable names (Boost_ vs. BOOST_) did the trick:

```
target_link_libraries(Playground ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
                                  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```